# How to source the file permanently

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

every time I open the terminal try to run the package launch file but it always have to source the file first before to launch the file.

does there any way can source the file permanently?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232231/how-to-source-the-file-permanently/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is explained in the Installation tutorial, section 1.6 - *Environment setup* (here from the [Jade tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#jade.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup)):

> It's convenient if the ROS environment variables are automatically added to your bash session every time a new shell is launched:

> ```
> echo "source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
> ```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Note also the warning:

> If you have more than one ROS distribution installed, `~/.bashrc` must only source the `setup.bash` for the version you are currently using.

> If you just want to change the environment of your current shell, you can type:

> ```
> source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
> ```

Btw: `source`ing is never 'permanent'. It will *always* only update the shell in which it was invoked.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-04-19**:
Thank you! it work for me.

**Comment by [ranjeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/39282/ranjeet/) on 2021-01-31**:
It does not work, there must be some error in the syntax.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-31**:
If you're using a different ROS release, you'll have to update the command and replace `jade` with whatever ROS release you're using.